# Linux terminal with custom buttons to execute scripts or commands

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm aiming to improve my terminal usage for software development by creating a dashboard. First of all I want splits, vertical/horizontal, this is already possible with Tilix or Terminator (I don't really like Tmux). But I'm missing a way to run scripts with my mouse. I run scripts often, like to clean or check the code. What I do is focus the terminals, press up arrow, and Enter, which is not as easy as clicking a button.

Is there a terminal that allows adding buttons at the top (or elsewhere), that allows me to run custom commands or scripts? For instance clicking "Check" might run "scripts/check.sh", which should run in a specific terminal and show its output.

Another button I'd use would be a button to restart a running program, like to update it after I changed the code.

Comment: I personally would prefer to keyboard shortcuts over mouse strokes any time. That's why for those type of tasks I use GNU `screen` and set up key binding for specific operations using `stuff` or `paste`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `Terminator`'s `Custom Commands Menu` plugin.

Enable it in Terminator's Preferences, and then in the right-click menu... it should be pretty obvious.

If you'd like to have buttons instead of menu entries, it's probably a relatively easy Python and GTK programming challenge to modify Terminator's user interface accordingly.

Also I think you'll want to modify Terminator's source not to add a trailing `\n`, i.e. not to execute the command immediately. It should be very easy to find the plugin's source (inside Terminator's official source) and within that the place where the newline is appended. (I think upstream would happily accept a patch that adds a corresponding UI toggle.)

---

Here's why I think only a few terminal emulators have such a feature.

> For instance clicking "Check" might run "scripts/check.sh", which should run in a specific terminal and show its output.

When you start up a terminal, it almost always(*) also runs a process: typically your shell.

You cannot "run" another program in the same terminal in the same fashion, *next to* your shell. The two would fight against each other for input, and maybe other resources as well. What you surely mean by "run" is to ask the already running *shell* to run your apps.

The way to do that is to pretend that you press the corresponding keys, i.e. synthesize input to the terminal (which then forwards them to the shell). [This particular step, in the Custom Commands plugin's source, is done using the `vte.feed_child()` method.]

But there's an inherent problem with this. You cannot know if the shell is at its prompt where it's expecting input, whether the input line is currently empty, and no special mode (e.g. repeat count for a letter) is enabled. I.e. you cannot know if these input characters will be interpreted literally and form a command that you wish to execute.

You can have a partial command already entered, and then your desired button will add text to that. You can be in an app where each individual keystroke invokes a menu or something. You can be in vim's command mode where injectcing a string like `scripts/check.sh` will execute all sorts of random vim editing commands on the file. Etc.

In some contexts, pasting a predefined text does exactly what you want it to do. In other contexts it can easily cause a lot of harm. And the terminal can't really tell which one is going to happen, therefore cannot protect you against such mistakes.

That's why, instead of such UI features, people tend to prefer shell aliases and functions, or interactive shell command editing and related features (like history search).

---

(*) If you go down the rabbit hole of programming against VTE (the terminal emulation library that Terminator uses), you'll find that it *is* possible not to run any command (not even the shell), just have that terminal sit there idle, and then you can add a button that starts up your preferred command directly in that terminal. Once it completes, you can fire up another command using one of the buttons. But again: there's no shell then which you could type the next command into. In this case you don't have to worry about the context. I'm really not sure however whether exploring this possibility is worth the efforts for you.

Comment: Custom Commands is interesting, but a button would be easier. I guess the only option would be patching Terminator. What I've been doing is injecting commands through xdotool. First I trigger a ctrl+c to stop any program. Then ctrl+u to make sure it works properly, then "write" a command, then trigger Return. If I keep the tiles constant I could set my xdotool script with my wm to focus and trigger on specific tiles by using coordinates, that's another option.

Comment: Yet another replacement for `xdotool`, if you know the tty line number (as in e.g. `/dev/pts/8`), can be to inject bytes using `ioctl(fd, TIOCSTI, &byte)` (one byte per call). See `man ioctl_tty`. This is the most generic: it works regardless of the choice of terminal emulator as well as windowing system (if any). But if you like Terminator's Custom commands functionality, except for its UI representation, then I'd probably start by patching Terminator, changing as few things as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know.

You might, if you use some form of split-terminal, run `dialog` in one of the two sides, for example:

```
list=( */ )
folder=$( dialog --title "List directory" --cancel-label "Exit" \
                 --no-items --menu "Please choose one folder: " \
                 --output-fd 1 10 40 0 ${list[@]///} )
echo $folder
```

And depending a bit on your terminal, that may make it possible to use your mouse.

But, unless you run in console-mode, which hardly anyone does, it is far easier to just create a separate window. Look at `tk` and your favourite language (TCL/Tk, Perl/Tk, Python tkinter or even Bash/Tk) on how to do that.

If you want to embed a terminal window in your dashboard, you might use:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
termf = Frame(root, height=400, width=500)
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)    
termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
wid = termf.winfo_id()
os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 400x500 -sb -e "ls; sleep 10" &' % wid)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I did try to make this dashboard with tkinter. But the terminal widget I found was very limited: https://github.com/Saadmairaj/tkterminal --- Would the dialog option allow me to see the output of the commands?

Comment: The question would be then, can I target a specific split pane from a terminal like Terminator to execute a command?

Comment: I still do not understand why it is such a bad idea to have a separate window for the dashboard.

Comment: A separate window would work, but I would need the output to be displayed on a real terminal that is already tiled and set for a purpose, thus I'd need to target a terminal and a specific tile/pane.

Comment: Yes, and? `xterm -e 'ls; sleep 5'` will give you a terminal. Or `xterm -hold "your command" &` Or, if you want all the output in the same terminal: `xterm -e "mkfifo myterm; tail -f myterm"` and throw your STDOUT and STDERR in the FIFO (`ls > myterm 2>&1`) Or even throw that into the `xterm` in the Python code in my answer.